# TCPClient in asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have asp.net mvc app that shows varios events. All events stored in a database. But now, I have to load data from the database and remote program. This program have external service (this is simple program that listening specific `TCP` port and recieve a query and send xml back).

And, I wrote simple page for test that connects to external program. The code got from MSDN:

```
static string Connect(String server, String message) 
{
  try 
  {
    // Create a TcpClient.        
    Int32 port = 9197;
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);

    // Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
    Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);         

    // Get a client stream for reading and writing.
   //  Stream stream = client.GetStream();

    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

    // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); 

    // Receive the TcpServer.response.

    // Buffer to store the response bytes.
    data = new Byte[256];

    // String to store the response ASCII representation.
    String responseData = String.Empty;

    // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
    Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);                


    stream.Close();         
    client.Close();  
    return responseData;
  } 
  catch (ArgumentNullException e) 
  {
    //
  } 
  catch (SocketException e) 
  {
    //
  }  

}
```

This is my action:

```
public ActionResult GetData()
        {           

            string query = "some query";

            var response = Connect("192.168.0.1", query);
            var model =  ParseResponse(response);
            return View(model);
        }
```

I think this solution will reduce the perfomance.

What is best practicies to use TCPClient in ASP.NET MVC 3 app?
What you think about my code?
Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think this solution will reduce the perfomance.

Well. All/most database operations are done over sockets. And you do not notice that, do you?

The most likely performance issues are:

1. Your server
2. Server location
3. Connection setup

The only thing I would do now is to build in checks in the client to monitor the response time and write to a log (or send an email) when the response times are too high.

***Don't try to optimize performance until that happen.***

Solutions for the above mentioned issues:

1. Refactor and optimize
2. Either put the server on the same lan or create a cache proxy server.
3. Use connection pooling instead of disconnecting the connections every time.

Answer (score 0):

> I think this solution will reduce the perfomance.

It's as any other remote request that your server does - an I/O intensive operation. So you could use an [asynchronous controller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx) and the asynchronous versions of the TcpClient methods. This way you won't be jeopardizing any worker threads on your server during the execution of the remote request.